# What is the right syntax to post sequentially named inputs in php?

Tags: php, loops, post

I am not a developer by trade or employ `<--` just a disclaimer

So, I have an html form with several hundred inputs, in essence a limited, mock spreadsheet.

The form is 3 columns by 150 rows.

For demonstration's sake, let's say that the form/table structure looked like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_1" /><input name="that_row_1" /><input name="the-other_row_1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_2" /><input name="that_row_2" /><input name="the-other_row_2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_3" /><input name="that_row_3" /><input name="the-other_row_3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ( . . . ) -->
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_150" /><input name="that_row_150" /><input name="the-other_row_150" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the form is posted to the PHP, I am looking for the right syntax to assign handlers (right word?) in a loop(s).

I don't know much in coding, but I have been playing and testing this type of variation/concept:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $_POST['[name="this_row_' + i + '"]']; $i++)
{
   echo $_POST['[name="this_row_' + i + '"]'][$i] + "," + $_POST['[name="that_row_' + i + '"]'][$i] + "," + $_POST['[name="the-other_row_' + i + '"]'][$i];
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work, and if it isn't already hinted, I want to write a new CSV file with column headers as the end game.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better: most of the time you can just name them `that_row[]` -- without any numbers -- and pull them out as an array from PHP with `$_POST['that_row']`. You can then iterate with a simple `foreach`, again without involving any indexes.

Comment: @Jon thanks for your tip, clearly that is the key.

Comment: @CaptainCarl thanks also for your second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$file=fopen(<DIRECTORY_PATH>."file.csv","w");
 if(!$file){
    //error
 }

$this_row=$_POST['this_row'];//consider sanitizing/cleaning the data
$that_row=$_POST['that_row']; //consider sanitizing/cleaning the data
$the_other_row=$_POST['the_other_row']; //consider sanitizing/cleaning the data

$loop=count($this_row); // assuming count of all the other columns are same

$csv_data="";
for($i=0;$i<$loop; $i++){

    $csv_data.=$this_row[$i].", ".$that_row[$i].", ".$the_other_row[$i].", ";
    //remove the last comma
    $csv_data.="\n";
    }
}

fwrite($file,$csv_data);
```

Comment: It's worth adding that this solution also requires the change which [Jon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @FDL, why the down vote? Of course I assume the input elements are named like what @Jon mentioned (like `<input name="this_row[]" />`). Unless, you can't iterate through it right? So what is the problem with that?

Comment: @Bere Thanks to you, and all of course, your code example was just on the level of my novice abilites!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your markup.

If you have multiple fields that mean the same (i.e. should have the same name with numbers, like in your example). You should be naming them `name="whateverNameYouWant[]"` (yes, all of them, with the same name). This will cause PHP to tread those inputs as an **array of inputs**, and you'll be able to access them like so `$_POST["whateverNameYouWant"][42]`.

When you do that, everything is simpler.

As for the CSV, PHP has **[functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)** to deal with CSV files. And now you can easily loop and access your $_POST variables as `$_POST["this_row"][$i]`, etc.